# How can I validate credentials in gmail?

Tags: python

I am trying to work in python to make a function that you give two parameters, checks them on gmail, and returns 1 or 0 if you could login with it. For example

```
validate("realmail@gmail.com","correctPass") -> This is 1
validate("wrong@gmail.com","incorrectPass") -> This is 0
```

How can I make this? I can't understand even where to begin.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is [poorly written](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), but you can use [imaplib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imaplib.html) to connect to `imap.gmail.com` and check the credentials, something like:

```
def gmail_checker(username,password):
        import imaplib
        i=imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
        try:
                i.login(username,password)
                if "OK Gimap" in i.welcome :
                    return True
        except:
                return

if ( gmail_checker('username','password') ) :
    print("Valid Credentials")
else:
    print("Invalid Credentials")
```

---

Forked and modified from original [checkemail.py](https://gist.github.com/joshbirk/1627326) into [gmail_check_credentials.py](https://gist.github.com/x011/eb3d193213f5240bb74bcc2d0854ea74)

---

PS: Make sure [less secure apps access](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en) is enabled on your gmail account.

Comment: It doesn't really work. I have placed a known working account and it said  invalid creds.

Comment: I've tested the code above and it works as intended. If you're trying to access an account that isn't yours or don't have less secure apps access enabled, it wont work.